# Find String in String backwards, starting from specific point

Tags: vb.net, indexof

I have a text, in this text I search for a file. I find it by searching for its extension but don't know the name  of the file.
When I find this string, I have the index of the extension (indexof(".jpg"))

Now, I would need the full file name. The only thing I know is that the filename starts right after a ">" symbol, but there are many of these in the file. Is there a way for example to get the index of the ">" in a string, starting at a specific index, and going backwards?

Comment: can you split the string by ">" and test each item in the result to see which fits best as the file name?

Comment: could just use regex...something like `>.+\.(jpg)|(JPG)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
>([A-Za-z0-9-+. _]+[.]jpg)
```

or perhaps better:

```
>([^[\]\*\/\\<>|]+[.]jpg)
```

I'm probably missing an allowed character, but that covers most of it and should be easy enough to modify. Use the expression like this:

```
Public Iterator Function FindJPGFileNames(inpupText As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
     For Each match In RegEx.Matches(inputString, ">([^[\]\*\/\\<>|]+[.]jpg)")
         Yield match.Groups(1).Value
     Next match
End Function
```

or

```
Public Function FindJPGFileNames(inpupText As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim matches = RegEx.Matches(inputString, ">([^[\]\*\/\\<>|]+[.]jpg)")
    Return matches.Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, does this also work for multiple filenames in the same string? I started with indexof in the first place because it allows me to ass a start index and go on to the next file once the first one is processed.

Comment: Yes. The function will return a sequence with all .jpg files

Answer (score 0):

or in addition I also found this solution:

```
Private Function searchimages(ByVal s As String, ByVal ending As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim los As New List(Of String)

    Dim position As Integer = 0
    While position <> -1
        position = s.IndexOf(ending, position, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        If position <> -1 Then

            Dim endPosition As Integer = position + ending.Length
            Dim startposition As Integer = s.LastIndexOf(">", position - 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 1

            los.Add(s.Substring(startposition, endPosition - startposition))

            position = endPosition
        End If
    End While
    Return (los)
End Function
```